# How to remove workspaces with xfce?

Tags: 14.04, xfce, workspaces

I have accidentally created a lot of workspaces in xfce

[image]

Now how to delete some of them?

Comment: Right click on one of the workspace, choose *Workspace Settings* and adopt the  *Number of Workspaces*.

Comment: @Thomas it would be better if post your comment as answer ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eEzn.png) is a screeshot for it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure the number of workspaces, right click on one of the workspace, choose *Workspace Settings* and adopt the *Number of Workspaces* to your needs.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eEzn.png) you can find a screenshot of the menu that opens (thanks to N0rbert).